# Ninject bind two different parameters of same type in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I have a web app with two different controllers and I use configuration files as input to the controllers. Earlier I was just using one single configuration file and could just bind that to the kernel and everything would work just fine. Now however I will be using two separate config files and need ninject to understand which one to use. Here is an example of how I thought I would do. Commented away is also what i did to bind the configuration before when I only had one.

```
        var kernel = NinjectWebApi.Kernel;
        //get base dependency instances from the container
        var configurationClient = kernel.Get<IConfigurationClient>();

        //initialise local dependencies
        var config1 = configurationClient.Get(new GetConfigurationByKeyRequest("Config1"));
        var config2 = configurationClient.Get(new GetConfigurationByKeyRequest("Config2"));

        //bind local dependencies

//This is what I did when I had just one config
        //kernel.Bind<IConfiguration>().ToMethod(c => config1.Configuration); 

        kernel.Bind<IMy1Controller>().To<My1Controller>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("config1", config1.Configuration)
            .WithConstructorArgument("config2", config2.Configuration);

            kernel.Bind<IMy2Controller>().To<My2Controller>()
                .WithConstructorArgument("config2", config2.Configuration);

        //Set the dependency resolver to use ninject
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
```

What is the purpose of "WithConstructorArgument" if I can't use it to specify an input?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I found a solution. But I am not sure this is the proper way.

```
var kernel = NinjectWebApi.Kernel;
    //get base dependency instances from the container
    var configurationClient = kernel.Get<IConfigurationClient>();

    //initialise local dependencies
    var config1 = configurationClient.Get(new GetConfigurationByKeyRequest("Config1"));
    var config2 = configurationClient.Get(new GetConfigurationByKeyRequest("Config2"));

    //bind local dependencies
    kernel.Bind<IConfiguration>().ToMethod(c => config1.Configuration).Named("config1");

    kernel.Bind<IConfiguration>().ToMethod(c => config1.Configuration).Named("config1"); 

    kernel.Bind<IMy1Controller>().To<My1Controller>()

        kernel.Bind<IMy2Controller>().To<My2Controller>()

    //Set the dependency resolver to use ninject
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
```

And to make ninject know which one to use I need to change the signature slightly in the constructor:

```
public My1Controller([Named("Config1")] IConfiguration config1)
```